# Best fit of point cloud to another point cloud in python

Tags: python, point, best-fit

I have the following problem:

From a txt-file I have two arrays with x,y,z coordinates of each point cloud and a temperature value. I extracted the coordinate lists out of two fem-files. Both describe a similar part but the distance from point to point are different in each point cloud.

Now I want to match the first point cloud to the other. At the end I want to map the temperature value of the first point cloud to the second point cloud.

- `Array_1 [point_index, x-coordinate, y-coordinate, z-coordinate, temp. value]`
- `Array_2 [point_index, x-coordinate, y-coordinate, z-coordinate]`

Goal: Array_2 with the temp value of the nearest point of Array_1 after fitting the point clouds on each other.

[image: Sample Picture]

Thank you for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand what is your goal, but point cloud registration sounds like what you are looking for.
See if this fits your goal -
http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.7.0/tutorial/Basic/icp_registration.html

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner Thanks for your comment, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I wrote it just because your risk that someone downvote your answer, making your reputation go down. I suggest you to transfer its content into a comment, as soon as you can - or to elaborate the answer.